# How to update nothing in an update fuction in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-update

I have a form where user details are updated. Once the page uploads the user will get a few fields loaded with the current database values.

I can allow them to upload images, but it's optional. Once the form is submitted all fields are updated but the problem is with the images. How can i not update the image field at all but still use it in the update function I have.

Is this a possible way of doing it ?

```
if (empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {
    // No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}
```

This is my function:

```
public function update_header($pageTitle,$title, $slogan, $logo, $titleChoice, $sloganChoice, $logoChoice){
    global $pdo;

    $sql= "UPDATE `header` SET `pageTitle`=?,`title`=?,`slogan`=?,`logo`=?,`titleChoice`=?,`sloganChoice`=?,`logoChoice`=? WHERE `header_ID` =1";

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $query -> execute(array($pageTitle,$title, $slogan, $logo, $titleChoice, $sloganChoice, $logoChoice));

    return "has been successfully updated!!";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can detect whether a user wants to change the image, and if not, don't include the image-related columns/values in the update query.

Comment: Well yes, I guess you can do two different statement, one with img update, other without

Comment: but is there not an easier neater way of doing so?

if (empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {
    // No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I not update the image field at all but still use it in the update function I have.

If you can't modify the `update_header()` function then it's not possible. The thing is, the SQL query inside the function affects the `logo` field. So either value you pass in `$logo` parameter in `update_header` function will be [converted to string (`PDO::PARAM_STR`)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), and eventually will replace the current value of the `logo` field.

If you can modify the `update_header()` function... One way of handling this optional field is to place the `if (empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {` clause inside the function and distinguish the behavior based on the value, e.g.:

```
public function update_header($pageTitle, $title, $slogan, $logo, $titleChoice, $sloganChoice, $logoChoice) {
    global $pdo;

    if ( ! empty($logo) {
        $sql= "UPDATE `header` SET `pageTitle`=?,`title`=?,`slogan`=?,`logo`=?,`titleChoice`=?,`sloganChoice`=?,`logoChoice`=? WHERE `header_ID` =1";
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($pageTitle,$title, $slogan, $logo, $titleChoice, $sloganChoice, $logoChoice));
    } else { // logo empty, then do not update the field
        $sql= "UPDATE `header` SET `pageTitle`=?,`title`=?,`slogan`=?,`titleChoice`=?,`sloganChoice`=?,`logoChoice`=? WHERE `header_ID` =1";
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($pageTitle,$title, $slogan, $titleChoice, $sloganChoice, $logoChoice));
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this help! What i have done is grab the data already in the table and re-enter it if its not changed and if it is changed i update it with the new variable. Do you think the way i have done it is better or is this way better? or are both similar. @bostaf

Comment: @user3032640 There's also the third approach - instead of updating existing record, remove it and re-enter. I think that if you're more comfortable with your solution, then it's better than what I proposed. Personally I think that none of the three approaches is better in general. They might be better in some specific applications / conditions, but not in general.